# Hide/Show table columns dynamicly with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have a button, when I press it, I must show a hidden column I have in my table. But my problem is that I only show one row.

```
<a href="#" class="btn-xl btn-default" id="btn_callkit" onclick="call();return false;" style="width: 150px;color: white;">KIT</a> 
 <table id="example0" class="table  table-striped">

        <br/>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="kit_head" style="display:none;">KIT</th>
                    <th>Material</th>
                    <th>Info</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
```

```
                    <?php
                        $rol = mysql_query("SELECT * from pg  WHERE pg.dataset = 2 ");
                            if (mysql_num_rows($rol) != 0) { 
                                while($item = mysql_fetch_array($rol)) { 


                                    $id = $item['id'];  
                                    $info = $item['info'];  
                                    $code = $item['lote_code'];
                    ?>

             <tr id="infodata_<?=$id;?>">


                    <td id="line" style="display:none;">

                        <div class="checkbox  checkbox-circle" style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
                            <input id="check_<?=$id;?>" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="check_<?=$id;?>">

                            </label>
                        </div>

                    </td>

                    <td><?php echo $info;?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $code;?></td>


                </tr>
        <? }} ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

My Javascript has this code:

```
function call()
{
    document.getElementById('kit_head').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('line').style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

What may I do it to show all of the rows that my database has inside?

Comment: Try using a `class` instead of an `id`, e.g. use `<th class="toggleColumn"` and `document.getElementByClass('toggleColumn')`

Comment: You are specifically changing the display of the first element that have an id of "Line" and "kit_head". Instead you can go with <tr> that wrap

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ID for the cell `line`.

`getElementById` - as the name implies - will return a single element, this will always be true because IDs are intended for single use. So your code:

`document.getElementById('line').style.display = 'block';`

Is getting the first matching element and setting the style attribute as defined.

Instead you should use a `class` which is intended to be the designation of many related elements or elements sharing common rules.

Then you can get all matching elements, loop over them and set the desired style attribute.

The DOM API exposes lots of methods for retrieving elements by their class name, you should consult the list of browser versions you intend to support and pick an appropriate technique from those available.

**Edit:**
As a sidenote, KennyDope is correct in saying that best practice is generally to toggle classes in order to manipulate styles. It's much easier to keep track of and modify classes than it is inline styles.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Always use classes when an element name will be reused.

Comment: My problem is that now it appears  "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClass is not a function"

Comment: Because that isn't a valid method, probably a typo from another answer. Take a look at the docs on Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: A few options from the top of my head are `getElementsByClassName` `querySelector` `querySelectorAll` pay attention to what these methods return and how to iterate over the results, it's not always intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to toggle classes instead of inline styles.

Your code will then something like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td class="toggle">Toggle field</td>
        <td class="toggle">Toggle field</td>
        <td>Other field</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="btn_callkit">toggle</button>

<script>
   function toggle (t) {
        var listTd = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < listTd.length; i++) {           
            listTd[i].classList.toggle('hidden');
        }           
    }

    document.getElementById('btn_callkit').addEventListener('click', toggle);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` property must be unique on the page.

Conversely, `class` property is, as the name suggests, a class of objects, and multiple objects can share the same class.

So if you want to show/hide a column, the specific `<td>` in each row must be assgined the same class, which then will be manipulated by Javascript, using `getElementByClassName`.

NB, `getElementByClassName` returns an array of objects, and you have to walk the array to change the display style in each.